# Rails: How to Customise Foundation JS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm using Rails and Foundation 5.5.3. Foundation loads all the `.js` files that I don't really need and I would like to remove them.

I found a few solutions for an older version of Foundation, but can't figure out how it works for my version.

I tried to follow this tutorial, I can't find that `index.js` file anywhere (he starts explaining around 10:00): http://railscasts.com/episodes/417-foundation?autoplay=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `//= require foundation` inside my `application.js` file and added what I needed:

```
//= require foundation/foundation
//= require foundation/foundation.dropdown
//= require foundation/foundation.abide
//= require foundation/foundation.tooltip
//= require foundation/foundation.topbar
```